# Writing A Global Path Planner As Plugin in ROS with rosmake?

Tags: rosmake, nav-core, pluginlib, ros-groovy, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,
I try to do this tutorial :http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS

But as i work on groovy i can't use catkin_make with the costmap_2d. So i have tried this tutorial with rosmake.

My probleme is: I can't load my plugin.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/global_planner.cpp)
```

manifest.xml

```
<package>
  <description brief="set_path_plug">

     set_path_plug

  </description>
  <author>Guillaume</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <depend package="message_generation"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="tf"/>
  <depend package="costmap_2d"/>
  <depend package="nav_core"/>
  <depend package="geometry_msgs"/>
  <depend package="angles"/>
  <depend package="base_local_planner"/>
  <export>
    <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/global_planner_plugin.xml" />
  </export>

</package>
```

global_planner_plugin.xml   (I have tried library path=
with the full path)

```
 <library path="lib">
  <class name="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" type="global_planner::GlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>This is a global planner plugin.</description>
  </class>
 </library>
```

And my .cpp and .h are the same than in the tutorial.

when i launch a move_base with this globalplanner i have this error:

```
[FATAL] [1406644445.324290214, 939.388000000]: Failed to create the global_planner/GlobalPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class global_planner/GlobalPlanner with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner navfn/NavfnROS pr2_navigation_controllers/GoalPasser
```

I think the problem come from my manifest.xml, the export is not correct.
Is it possible the make a plugin with rosmake? (when I rosmake everything going well)
If someone have an idea?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188191/writing-a-global-path-planner-as-plugin-in-ros-with-rosmake?/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 312 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

manifest.xml

```
<package>
  <description brief="set_path_plug">
     set_path_plug
  </description>
  <author>Guillaume</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/set_path_plug</url>
  <depend package="message_generation"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="tf"/>
  <depend package="costmap_2d"/>
  <depend package="nav_core"/>
  <depend package="geometry_msgs"/>
  <depend package="angles"/>
  <depend package="base_local_planner"/>
  <depend package="pluginlib"/>

  <export>
    <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/global_planner_plugin.xml" />
  </export>

</package>
```

global_planner_plugin.xml

```
 <library path="lib/libset_path_plug">
 <!-- <class name="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" type="global_planner::GlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">-->
<class name="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" type="global_planner::GlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>This is a global planner plugin.</description>
  </class>
 </library>
```

and PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(set_path_plug, global_planner_plugin, global_planner::GlobalPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)  at the begining of the .cpp file.

I was not able to see the output because i forgot the argument output="screen" for my move_base_node in my launchfile

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) with karma: 312 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0